# conditional fill in d3.js for area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an area graph (supposed to represent a time series).  I want to color the graph based on the y value such that for regions where the y > c it is one color and for the area where y<=c it is another color.  Is this possible in D3?

This is the code I have that generates a single color graph:

```
var width = 700,
    height = 400;

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height); 

var mpts = [{"x":0,"val":15}];
var n = 200;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(Math.random()>.5)
    {
        mpts = mpts.concat({"x":i+1,"val":mpts[i].val*(1.01)});
    }
    else
    {
        mpts = mpts.concat({"x":i+1,"val":mpts[i].val*(.99)});
    }
}

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,n]).range([10,10+width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,20]).range([height-10,0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.val); })
        .y0(function(d) { return y(0); });

vis.append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d",area(mpts))
        .attr("fill","orange");

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the way you add the areas to something like

```
    vis.selectAll("path").data(mpts).enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return (d.val > c ? "orange" : "yellow"); });
```

Comment: what's the "definition" area?  I tried adding to the .append("path") and the d3.svg.area() statement, neither seem to work.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-area) has some more information. I'm sorry, I should have had a closer look -- you also need to change how you create the paths. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I understand why this should work, but it just creates an a long list of empty path elements, unless I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do now. Using `[mpts]` instead of `mpts` as the argument to `.data()` draws the graph, but I'm guessing that what you want is different colours for each bar? You would have to generate separate paths for each of the data points to achieve this, i.e. `mpts` would need to be an array of arrays where each array describes the rectangle for a y value.

Comment: gotcha...I think i'm just going to approximate a solution by drawing rectangles with a certain fill